# MYSQL adding OR clause in left join slowing up the query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, on-clause

I have two database tables: **orders** and **customers**.

I'm running a SQL to get all orders in June month.

If the **Ship To** and **Bill To** email are different, we are inserting two different records with both emails to **customers** table.

```
select o.order_id
     , o.total
     , c.customer_email 
  from orders o 
  left 
  join customers c
    ON o.bill_email = c.customer_email
    OR o.ship_email = c.customer_email
 where DATE(o.order_date) >= '2020-06-01'
```

But this SQL is taking too much time to load because of the condition,

```
ON o.bill_email=c.customer_email 
OR o.ship_email=c.customer_email
```

How can I add both conditions in ON clause?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  Why bother with the joining at all?  The customer email is in the `orders` table.

Comment: I'm trying to get all orders in June month and in customers table we're storing order details in JSON format, so it is easy to join orders and customers to get the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `left join`s and put the results in separate columns rather than rows:

```
select o.order_id, o.total, cb.customer_email, so.customer_email
from orders o left join
     customers cb
     on o.bill_email = cb.customer_email left join
     customers cs
     o.ship_email = cs.customer_email
where o.order_date >= '2020-06-01';
```

Note that the `date()` function is not needed.

That said, this seems more easily expressed as:

```
select o.order_id, o.total, o.bill_email
from orders o 
where o.order_date >= '2020-06-01'
union all
select o.order_id, o.total, o.ship_email
from orders o 
where o.order_date >= '2020-06-01' and s.ship_email <> o.bill_email;
```